# Get EXIF Data from ImageField Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, exif

I'm on this task of extracting the exif data of a photo uploaded through DJANGO 2.1.2,

Here's my model.py

UPDATED MODEL:

```
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        "Uploaded image", upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename, height_field='height', width_field='width')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable = False)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable = False ) 
    camera = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable = False)
    latitud = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable = False)
    longitud = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable = False)
    meta = ExifField(
        source='image',
        denormalized_fields={
            'camera': exifgetter('Model'),
            'latitud': exifgetter('GPSLatitude'),
            'longitud': exifgetter('GPSLongitude'),
        },
    )
```

Some guidance of how to work with this model would gladly help.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Doesn't seem to be related to get_exif method itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also needed the EXIF information from images and could not find a good solution for that. That is why I developed a field for Django, which extracts the EXIF information using the [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and stores them in the database: [django-exiffield](https://pypi.org/project/django-exiffield/).

Simple install `django-exiffield`, make sure the `exiftool` is installed and add a new field to your model:

```
from exiffield.fields import ExifField


class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        "Uploaded image", upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename, 
    exif = ExifField(
        source='image',
    )
```

Since the `ExifField` used `JSONField` internally, you can access the individual values using the appropriate key, e.g. `print(image.exif['Model'])`.

If you need to filter your image by certain EXIF values or need to access some of them very often, it makes sense to [denormalize](https://github.com/escaped/django-exiffield#denormalizing-fields) them. The module provides an easy way to do that, eg. denormalize the camera model:

```
from exiffield.fields import ExifField
from exiffield.getters import exifgetter


class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    camera = models.CharField(
        editable=False,
        max_length=100,
    )
    exif = ExifField(
        source='image',
        denormalized_fields={
            'camera': exifgetter('Model'),
        },
    )
```

You can find more information about the module in its [readme](https://github.com/escaped/django-exiffield/blob/master/README.rst).

If you have any question feel free to ask and if there are any problems with the module please open an issue in the GitHub repository!

Comment: A couple of questions, im trying to get 5 exif fields, im specifying the fields but it returns all the exif fields plus the ones i defined ¿How to just get the ones i want to?, on the other side, im trying to get the latitude and longitude num value, is possible to do this? it just gives me the val value,

Comment: could you please provide some code and tell me which fields you are trying to access/use?

In general, the `ExifField` always stores all exif information, which was extracted by the `exiftool`. If you only need certain fields, I recommend to store them as separate fields on the model (see [denormalized](https://github.com/escaped/django-exiffield#denormalizing-fields)). You just need to know the name of the exif value and add the corresponding definition and fields.

Comment: I updated the question with the actual code im working on, as i say, when i see the results of the returning exif data, its brings me all fields plus the ones i defined in the model

Comment: How do you access the EXIF values.

Comment: question :) I installed ExifField & exiftool (pip)

from exiffield.fields import ExifField
from exiffield.getters import exifgetter
import exiftool

I got this after: python manage.py makemigrations

nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E001) `exiftool` not found.
        HINT: Please install `exiftool.`
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E006) `camera` not found on <class 'nutriscore.models.Picture'>.
        HINT: Check spelling or add field to model.
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E006) `latitud` not found on <class 'nutriscore.models.Picture'>

Comment: here is my models:

class Picture(models.Model):
    catego = models.ForeignKey(Catego,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="catego_pictures")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nutriscore/')
    meta = ExifField(
        source='image',
        denormalized_fields={
            'camera': exifgetter('Model'),
            'latitud': exifgetter('GPSLatitude'),
            'longitud': exifgetter('GPSLongitude'),
        },
    )
    ...

Comment: @Louis In order to be able to use `django-exiffield` you need to install the exiftool itself: https://exiftool.org/ . Install instruction might differ depending on your operating system. If you are using ubuntu, you can simply install it by running: `sudo apt-get install exiftool`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, instead of relying on an external package / customized field, goes below.

It saves the EXIF of the image to a JSONField which can be queried per Django's [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield).

```
class UploadedImage(CreatedUpdatedByMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    image_exif = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Class string added to store original name of image
    original_image_name = None

    # Ensure HEIC images (iPhone default) can be uploaded
    from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener
    register_heif_opener()

    # When the form is initialized save the original photo name
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_image_name = self.image.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # This checks if the photo was updated or not before saving EXIF.
        if self.original_image_name != self.image.name and not self.image.closed:

            # Extract EXIF
            image_open = Image.open(self.image)
            image_open.verify()
            image_get_exif = image_open.getexif()
            if image_get_exif:
                exif = {
                    # Ensure we're not getting "TypeError: Object of type IFDRational is not JSON serializable".
                    ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in image_get_exif.items()
                    if k in ExifTags.TAGS and type(v) not in [bytes, TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational]
                }
                
                self.image_exif = json.dumps(exif)

       super(UploadedImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```