# Django : Geocoding with Picture Exif data - HINT: Please install `exiftool.`

Tags: python, django, localization, geolocation, geocoding

I hope you're well :)

I've successfully installed:

```
pip install django-exiffield

pip install PyExifTool
```

When I ty to makemigrations:

```
from exiffield.fields import ExifField
from exiffield.getters import exifgetter

import exiftool

class Picture(models.Model):
    catego = models.ForeignKey(Catego,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="catego_pictures")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nutriscore/')
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    meta = ExifField(
        source='image',
        denormalized_fields={
            'camera': exifgetter('Model'),
            'latitud': exifgetter('GPSLatitude'),
            'longitud': exifgetter('GPSLongitude'),
        },
    )
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.catego.title
```

I got the following issue:

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
Is anyone has an idea about it?

ERRORS:
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E001) `exiftool` not found.
HINT: Please install `exiftool.`
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E006) `camera` not found on <class 'nutriscore.models.Picture'>.
HINT: Check spelling or add field to model.
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E006) `latitud` not found on <class 'nutriscore.models.Picture'>.
HINT: Check spelling or add field to model.
nutriscore.Picture.meta: (exiffield.E006) `longitud` not found on <class 'nutriscore.models.Picture'>.
HINT: Check spelling or add field to model.

Comment: What do you mean by "localisation"?

Comment: I mean geolocalization :) For instance when you take a picture with your Iphone. You can know where you have taken your picture (address, town, zip, country, ... thanks to the GPS coordinates.

Comment: There's an exif package which will help you get data from images. Take a look at this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859052/get-exif-data-from-imagefield-django-2-0

Comment: thanks @markwalker_